# How to move apex input fields to different page blocks\sections based on user input to a particular field on Visual force page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm new to Salesforce development. We have a requirement to move certain fields to a default page block from their original page block based on a picklist user selection. **Please share any approaches or links which will help me to achieve this.**

Comment: you can try out first and put your code here whenever you face issues

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use two `force:inputField` components bound to the same value provider (e.g. `{!account.Name}`). Then trigger an `apex:actionFunction` method from the `onchange` parameter of your picklist. The action function could then rerender the page blocks containing the mirrored `force:inputField` components.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the answers to all the `apex:pageblock`, then use the Rendered attribute to show them only the picklist is set the way for it to be appropriate. For example, assume you set boolean `showInTopSection` based on the picklist value. Something like below.

Controller:

```
public getShowInTopSection(){return pickval=='option1';}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:inputfield value="pickval"/>
<apex:pageBlock id="pageblock1">
    <apex:inputfield value="firstEdit" rendered="{!showInTopSection}"/>
    <apex:inputfield value="secondEdit" rendered={!showInTopSection}"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlock id="pageblock2">
    <apex:inputfield value="firstEdit" rendered="{!!showInTopSection}"/>
    <apex:inputfield value="secondEdit" rendered={!!showInTopSection}"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

This way the input fields will either be rendered into the top or the second section depending on how pickval is set.